# Updating android styles to recognize material components

Tags: android, android-styles, material-components-android

I just recently change the parent reference of my AppTheme, to have compatibility with recent tools, but now some old styles are not been applied..

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

And for example this button style is not working.

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dark_bb</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Which material library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When switching from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`, update your button style like this:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
  <item name="backgroundTint">@drawable/dark_bb</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Apply the style in your layout:

```
<Button
  style="@style/ButtonStyle"
  ...
/>
```

This ensures compatibility with Material Components theme.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, isn't there a work around to don't have to change al buttons in app layout?

Comment: sorry didn't get your doubt?

Comment: That way I'd have to update all manually, is there a way to use material without having to do that. The thing is if I don't change my AppTheme to material, my materialCalendar appear distorted...

Comment: To automatically apply Material styles to your existing widgets without manually updating each one, you can use the Material Components Bridge theme. The Bridge theme maps AppCompat attributes to their Material counterparts, allowing you to use Material Components without manually updating individual styles.

To use the Bridge theme, change your AppTheme parent in styles.xml:

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

Comment: I just try that, but still don't fix my display issues, to be more precise, I asked on another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76072877/materialcalendar-datepicker-appear-distorted